# search site and web in joomla

Tags: php, search, joomla

We have created a web using Joomla CMS. In this site we want to implement a feature by which a use can search for text in our website as well as on the whole web using some search engine like google or yahoo.

Is there any extension available which will allow one to search web site it is hosted on as well the whole web in a Joomla based web site? The extension should allow user to select as to where they want to search in current web site or the web. Preferred option is a free extension.

I have been searching for something like this for 2 days but have not found one so I am asking for help here.

Answer (score 0):

To provide searches on your website see the [MySQL Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

To search the web, just forget about it - you would need to store PB (petabytes) of storage.

Or use [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/).

Comment: Thanks I know this but it would be better to get a ready made Joomla extension as developing extension is a black art for us here.

Comment: Then this is not the place to ask, SuperUser would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer at: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search-a-indexing/site-search/9011

Thanks everyone for their time.